# test for in-tile for Dirichlet tile, using R

Tags: r, delaunay, spatstat, dirichlet

So I can take points and use the `R` libraries `deldir` or `spatstat::dirichlet` to find the dirichlet tesselation of those points.

Now I have a point not in the set, and I want to know the indices of the points forming the dirichlet tile which my not-in-set-point is interior to.  I can get there by knowing the tile label (or index).

Are there any libraries or methods to do this?  I'm thinking spatstat, but not finding something there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `cut.ppp()` can take a point pattern and find which tesselation
tile each point in the pattern belongs to. Below is the code for a simple
example of a point pattern that only contains a single point (0.5, 0.5).

```r
library(spatstat)
dd <- dirichlet(cells)
plot.tess(dd, do.labels = TRUE)
xx <- ppp(.5, .5, window = Window(dd))
plot(xx, add = TRUE, col = "red", cex = 2, pch = 20)
```

[image]

```r
yy <- cut(xx, dd)
yy
#> Marked planar point pattern: 1 point
#> Multitype, with levels = 
#>    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
#> 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
#> window: rectangle = [0, 1] x [0, 1] units
marks(yy)
#> [1] 18
#> 42 Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ... 42
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Ege_Rubak - thank you for the excellent answer.  What can you tell me about reprex?

Comment: The R package `reprex` just makes it easy to produce a reproducible example including code and plots in a format you can copy-paste into e.g. stackoverflow, GitHub or other places where you need to show your example. It has nothing to do with `spatstat` and the problem at hand per se.

Answer (score 0):

If `X` is a point pattern and `B` is a tessellation, then

```
M <- marks(cut(X, B))
```

returns a factor (vector of categorical values) identifying which tile contains each of the points of `X`. Alternatively,

```
M <- tileindex(X$x, X$y, B)
```

or

```
f <- as.function(B)
M <- f(X)
```